# AVL Tree insertion - Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

I am trying to solve this problem on Hackerrank ( https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/self-balancing-tree ) using their editor. The following are C++ function code I wrote:

```
node* makeNewNode (int data)
{
    node* temp= new node();
    temp->val=data;
    temp->left=NULL;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->ht=0;
    return temp;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
int height(node* temp)
{
    if(temp==NULL)
        return -1;
    return temp->ht;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
int balanceFactor(node* root)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    return height(root->left)-height(root->right);
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
node* rightrotation(node* root)
{
    node* temp1 = root->left;
    node* temp = temp1->right;
    temp1->right = root;
    root->left = temp;
    root->ht = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
    temp1->ht = max(height(temp1->left), height(temp1->right)) + 1;
    return temp1;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
node* leftrotation(node* root)
{
    node* temp = root->right;
    node* temp1 = temp->left;
    temp->left = root;
    root->right = temp1;
    root->ht = max(height(root->left), height(root->right)) + 1;
    temp->ht = max(height(temp->left), height(temp->right)) + 1;
   return temp;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------
node* insert( node* root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL)
        return makeNewNode(data);

    if(data<root->val)
        root->left = insert(root->left, data);
    else if(data>root->val)
        root->right = insert(root->right, data);
    else
        return root;

    root->ht = 1 + max(height(root->left), height(root->right));
    int balance = balanceFactor(root);

    if(data<root->left->val && balance>1)
        return rightrotation(root);

    if(data>root->right->val && balance<-1)
        return leftrotation(root);

    if(balance>1 && data > root->left->val)
    {
        root->left = leftrotation(root->left);
        return rightrotation(root);
    }

    if(balance<-1 && data < root->right->val)
    {
        root->right = rightrotation(root->right);
        return leftrotation(root);
    }

    return root;
}
```

I am getting Segmentation fault in the line `if(balance>1 && data > root->left->val)` but I can't figure out why. I tried putting a check for `root->left` is `null` before getting into this, but even that is giving seg fault.

Because I am using Hackerrank inbuilt editor, the main function is taken care of.

Nevertheless, for debugging purposes, I added the following main():

```
int main()
{
node* root=NULL;
root=insert(root,1);
root=insert(root,2);
root=insert(root,3);
return 0;
}
```

I tried an online gdb (www.onlinegdb.com) and it shows

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                                                     
0x0000000000400aa2 in insert (root=0x603010, data=2) at main.cpp:86                                                                      
86          if(data<root->left->val && balance>1)
```

Please help.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: The above roughly translates to: _"Could you please include what you do in `main()` and leave only the suspected - problematic functions in the above code, so that we can reproduce and confirm your error?"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write

```
if(data<root->left->val && balance>1)
```

if `root` or if `root->left` can be `nullptr`.

If your AVL Tree has only a root and if you are inserting on the right node, then `root->left == nullptr` and `root->right` is your inserted node.

So the execution will go on `data < root->left->val` and it will generate a segmentation fault. You need to insert more conditions like

```
if(root->left != nullptr && data<root->left->val && balance>1)
```

Here is the modified insert function:

```
node* insert( node* root, int data)
{
    ...
    int balance = balanceFactor(root);

    if(root->left && data<root->left->val && balance>1) // here was the segmentation fault with gdb
        return rightrotation(root);

    if(root->right && data>root->right->val && balance<-1)
        return leftrotation(root);

    if(balance>1 && root->left && data > root->left->val)
    { ... }

    if(balance<-1 && root->right && data < root->right->val)
    { ... }

    return root;
}
```

Comment: I already tried it and it did not help. I've mentioned it in the question detail.

Comment: @Bharg I have tried your main with gdb and the only error is that the condition `root->left != NULL` is missing in the `if`. With this condition, your program goes to the end.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I did not add that check in all four rotation conditions but only in two. Thanks!